# 404 Issue in Laravel API when required param value not passed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

**Request class**

```
class LoginRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'EmailAddress'  => 'required',
            'Password'      => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            "EmailAddress.required" => trans("login.RequiredEmailAddress"),
            "Password.required"     => trans("login.RequiredPassword")
        ];
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/AuthenticateUser', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'API\Login\apiLoginController@AuthenticateUser', 
        'as'   =>  'AuthenticateUser'
    )
);
```

**Controller Action Method**

I have a controller, I did so far for request class only to validate the input parameters. below is the action method

```
public function AuthenticateUser(LoginRequest $request) {
    dd("Hello");
}
```

**Url**

```
localhost:85/Laravel/public/api/v1/AuthenticateUser
```

I am using Postman Chrome extension to test the Url. So, as we can see that in the Request class both Email Address and the password are required parameters.

When I pass both parameters value. there is not issue and everything works. When I keep the Email Address value empty...I got 404 error and here is the screenshot.

Am I missing something to get rid of 404 error when Email address is not given? I am expecting an error message to enter Email Address

[image]

Below is the working state when I pass both email and password

[image]

Comment: It's most likely because you're entering the URI incorrectly. - Type `php artisan route:list` to view all your existing URIs, and try them. Why are you including the `Laravel/public` part of the URI as well? you generally don't need to add that, and also are you defining the prefix as `api/v1` in your routes file?

Comment: As I already mentioned in the question that it works if I pass both email address and password.

Comment: We're missing some information. You said it works if you provide both fields, but you should be seeing the result of a `dd('hello')`, but instead you're getting JSON back. The probable reason you're getting a 404 is because somewhere in your app, it's searching for an empty email address in your database, and not finding anything. You need to find the correct controller that is outputting the JSON to work out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working by changing the request class like below.

```
class LoginRequest extends Request
{

    public function wantsJson() {
        return true;
    }

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'EmailAddress'  => 'required',
            'Password'      => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            "EmailAddress.required" => trans("login.RequiredEmailAddress"),
            "Password.required"     => trans("login.RequiredPassword")
        ];
    }
}
```

just added below code.

```
public function wantsJson() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

I managed to get rid of the 404 and return a 422 by adding the following header in the request:

```
accept:application/json
```

This is not really a bug in Laravel as [Taylor pointed out](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/700798586636750848) but a way to differentiate if it is an AJAX/API request or not.

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively, if you don't want the client to specify that header, you can create a middleware that will add the header `accept:application/json` on every API requests. Here's how:

1. Create a new middleware: `app/Http/Middleware/ForceJsonResponse.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. In `/app/Http/Kernel.php`, inside `$middlewareGroups.api`, specify the namespace to your newly created middleware:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [...],
        'api' => [
            [...]
            \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Answer (score -2):

It is because you are validating directly on route handling and not matching throughs NotFoundException. You need to pass the Request to your Controller as is and do:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'EmailAddress'  => 'required|email',
            'Password'      => 'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: I doubt it would be because of this, simply because if the validation fails, Laravel returns a 422 error, not a 404

Comment: it works if I pass both email address and password. but does not work when i keep email address value empty. Please check screenshot in question

Comment: It returns 422 on failed validation, but on route it is not validation, it is route matching with NotFoundException aka status 404!!! And thanks for vote down, but it would be better to test, then down vote @PhilCross

Comment: I did nothing bro in voting. There are millions of users in this site. I added more screenshots in question.

Comment: I wrote the reason of 404, you can test on your code

Comment: I -1'd because I'm pretty much 100% certain the request class the OP provided is valid. If the OP trys your validation, and it works, I'll eat my words and +1 your answer, but AFAIK validation isn't the issue - or at least the request class. I do this type of requests in all my laravel apps, and never had this issue with validation.

Comment: hi all, it's fixed. I added the answer.

Comment: **WantsJson** means to return JSON response instead of throwing exception, but which status code are you getting? @Helper

Comment: 422 UnProcessable Entity

Comment: But **wantsJson** is not changing status codes, how can the same route return 404 on non-wantsJson and 422 on wantsJson?? The status code has to remain the same, wantsJson only changes the response format

Comment: You should check this file **vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php** and method `convertValidationExceptionToResponse` or **vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests.php** and method : `buildFailedValidationResponse`

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. But without WantsJson the 404 status was the reason of matching route